# Listing directory's files using open() and read() syscalls in POSIX systems

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system, systems-programming

I was wondering how to do this. I have tried several things but nothing seems to work for me. I don't want to use opendir() syscall nor do i want to use readdir() system call. Could you please tell me how to do this because i get garbage values. I want to list files that are inside a folder. I get garbage value stored in the buffer from this code.

```
char buffer[16];
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t bytes_read;
    
    int i;
    /* Open the file for reading. */
    int fd = open ("testfolder", O_RDONLY);
    /* Read from the file, one chunk at a time. Continue until read
    “comes up short”, that is, reads less than we asked for.
    This indicates that we’ve hit the end of the file. */
    do {
        /* Read the next line’s worth of bytes. */
        bytes_read = read (fd, buffer, 16);
        /* Print the offset in the file, followed by the bytes themselves.*/
        
        // printf ("0x%06lx : ", offset);
        // for (i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i)
        // printf ("%02x ", buffer[i]);
        printf("%s", buffer);
        printf ("\n");
        /* Keep count of our position in the file. */
        // offset += bytes_read;
    }
    while (bytes_read!=-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this.  The kernel only allows `open` on a directory with special options, and it doesn't allow `read` on a directory at all.  You have to use `opendir` and `readdir`.

(Under the hood, `opendir` calls `open` with those special options I mentioned, and `readdir` calls the private system call `getdents`.  See https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/opendir.c and https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir.c .  Doing this yourself is not recommended.)